# The program should display ‘Out of range’ if credits entered are not in the range 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 and 120

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

To try to solve the question above I tried by creating a list with the range and then a list with the variables in it. Then to check if the variables are in the list i used an if loop  however it is not working and only printing out "out of range...". I have also tried a while loop and it would just repeat the total 7 times. I do not know how to fix it and would please like an answer. Thank you

```
def main():
    a = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120]
    try:
        userPass = int(input("Enter pass credits: "))
        userDefer = int(input("Enter defer credits: "))
        userFail = int(input("Enter fail credits: "))
    except:
        print("Invalid number.")
    total = userFail + userPass + userDefer
    aValues = [ userPass, userFail, userDefer ]
    if aValues in a:
        print(total)
    else:
        print("Out of range. Try again")
    if total > 120:
        print("Total incorrect")
        repeat()
    else:
        if userPass >= 120:
            print("This student has progressed.")
            repeat()
        elif userPass >= 100 and total == 120:
            print("This student is trailing.")
            repeat()
        elif userFail <= 60 and total == 120:
            print("This student did not progress(module retreiver).")
            repeat()
        elif userPass <= userFail:
            print("This students program outcome is exclude.")
            repeat()
        else:
            print("incorrect. Try again.")
            repeat()
            
def repeat():
    choice = int(input("If you would like to quit type 1 or test another student write 2: "))
    if choice != 1 and choice != 2:
        repeat()
    else:
        while choice == 2:
            main()
        while choice == 1:
            break
        print("Thank you.")

main()
```

Comment: A (nearly) identical question was asked earlier today. If you're the same person, don't repost questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74549230/python-range-error-im-not-sure-how-to-make-the-program-display-out-of-range-if/74549412#74549412

Comment: `if aValues in a:` what does it do ?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `if all(v in a for v in aValues):`

Comment: As an aside, a big problem with this code is that it ignores errors and continues. Suppose the user enters a bad value, you catch the error, but then let the script continue - it will try to reference variables that were never defined and crash. Also, `except:` (catch everything) when you really just want `except ValueError:` is another classic bug.

Comment: For the first question, no I am not the same person.                                               
For loneWanderer thats the problem its suppose to check if the aValues are the values in the list a.                                                                                                             For tdelaney thank you for telling me my error could you please elaborate a bit more about the errors in my code if you can. Thank you                                                     Thank you all for your replies

Answer (score 0):

Testing whether one set of numbers is in another is a set operation. So use `set` and subtract all of the valid values from your input. If any values remain, they are not valid.

```
a = set([0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120])
if set([userPass, userFail, userDefer]) - a:
    print("Out of range. Try again")
```

Interestingly, you can also use a `range` object. It is built to check for containment efficiently

```
a = range(0, 121, 20)
if any(val in a, for val not in (userPass, userFail, userDefer)):
    print("Out of range. Try again")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am truly thankful for your answer and helping me understand

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the first if.

```
if aValues[0] in a and aValues[1] in a and aValues[2] in a :
    print(total)
```

if you need to put more values you can do this:

```
total=0
for i in range(len(aValues)):
  if(aValues[i] in a):
    total=total+ aValues[i]
  else:
    print('Incorrect Value')
print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply it greatly helped me witch finish my solution and i cant thank you enough.